# Como Llenar DataGridView desde el TextBox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, net

Estoy Insertando al datagridview una serie de números con lector de código de barras desde el evento TextChanged, pero lo que yo quiero es se inserte toda la cantidad de dígitos completos y no todo un árbol. como se ve ahí en la imagen.

Alguien podria ayudarme por favor. Esto es lo que he estado intentando:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
    }
    else 
    {
        string codigo = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(codigo);
    }
}
```

[image: esto es lo que que actualmente se ve]

Comment: creo que el evento textChange no es el indicado... usa otro evento

Comment: si todos tus codigos tienen la misma logitud lo que podrias hacer es que cuando el texto tenga esa longitud dada lo agregues al grid. o sino simplemente agrega un boton ('Agregar'), y cambia tu evento al click del boton.

Comment: @MiguelZarate los codigos son de distintas longitudes

Comment: Estas usando un escáner de código de barras? Pon ese código.

Comment: @Japv si estoy usando por eso lo registra asi piramidal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El **evento TextChanged** no es el indicado para eso ya que este evento se dispara cada vez que cambia el contenido del **TextBox**. Lo que te propongo es que uses el **evento KeyDown** del **TextBox** y cuando aprietes la **tecla Enter** es que se añada al **DataGridView**:

```
if(e.keyValue == 13)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
   {
      string codigo = textBox1.Text;
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(codigo);
   }
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es preguntar si se pulsó la **tecla Enter**(es el **caracter 13 en el código ASCII**). Posteriormente compruebo si el **TextBox** no está vacío mediante la **función IsNullOrWhiteSpace**, de no estar vacío pues añado el código al **DataGridView**.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias maestro, si funcionó con KeyDown.